# Swapping transmission 98-99 possible

Tags: engine, transmission, bmw

I’m wondering if my 99 Bmw 528i transmission with a bad engine can be a potential doner for a 98 bmw 528i with a good engine bad transmission help so I jump on the purchase before it’s to late

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! While I'm not a BMW expert, I understand parts are very swapable between years and models. Since the 98 and 99 are both 4th Generation 5-Series (E39) and out of the same model (528i), I doubt there'd be any issue with the swap. Hopefully someone on here could tell you for absolute sure for you to make the decision.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Wikipedia, it appears there were two different automatic transmissions used in 1999. Depending on when your car was manufactured.

The two autos are the:

- *GM 4L30E* - Used up until 06/98 manufacturing date.
- *GM 5L40E* - Used from 07/98 to 03/00 manufacturing dates (inclusive).

There was only one standard shift tranny for either of the years, the *S5D 250G*.

If you have an automatic transmission and it falls before the 07/98 manufacturing date, you should be fine. If after that, then the two would most likely be incompatible. It looks as though, the standard version shouldn't have an issue.

Note: Some information was pulled from [this source](http://www.e38.org/electran1.pdf).